# How to add pointer using for loops FAT Table C program

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system, block, allocation

```
index                    block           space
0                        0               1
1                        0               1
2                        0               1
3                        0               1
4                        0               1
5                        1               0
6                        1               0
7                        1               0
8                        1               0
9                        1               0
10                       2               0
11                       2               0
12                       2               0
13                       2               0
14                       2               0
15                       3               0
16                       3               0
17                       3               0
18                       3               0
19                       3               0
20                       4               0
21                       4               0
22                       4               0
23                       4               0
24                       4               0
```

I using a for loop to print out the table above from a structure. I have an array of available blocks {2,4} and an array with 6 items {6,7,8,9,10,11}. How can I print the table such that the space of the block will indicate the next block at the last item of the space. Have tried this for some time, would appreciate some help! Thank you!

availblock = {2,4}
itemsarr = {6,7,8,9,10,11}

```
index                    block           space
0                        0               1
1                        0               1
2                        0               1
3                        0               1
4                        0               1
5                        1               0
6                        1               0
7                        1               0
8                        1               0
9                        1               0
10                       2               6
11                       2               7
12                       2               8
13                       2               9
14                       2               4
15                       3               0
16                       3               0
17                       3               0
18                       3               0
19                       3               0
20                       4               10
21                       4               11
22                       4               0
23                       4               0
24                       4               0

index = 0
for (int i = 0; i < availblocklen; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        int currentblock = availblocklen[index];
        int availblkindex = (5 * currentblock) + j;
        for (int k = 0; k < (5 * availblock); k++) {
            freeindexarr[k] == availblkindex;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < itemsarr; x++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 65; k++) {
                if (struct.index == availblkindex) {
                    if ((k + 1) % 5 == 0) {
                        struct.index[k].space= availblk[index+1];
                    }
                    else {
                        struct[k].space = itemsarr[x];
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
    index++
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that you got so far then I will gladly help you.

Comment: Hi there, thank you. I've updated the post with the code that i have so far.

Comment: `freeindexarr[k] == availblkindex;` ==> `freeindexarr[k] = availblkindex;` in your for loop.